# hibernate 3.5 jar files

Tags: hibernate, jpa

We are migrating to new Hiberbate 3.5.0 final version from 3.3.2. As per the documentation copied the hibernate3.jar and hibernate-jpa-2.0-api-1.0.0.Final.jar and removed all the old jar files.
   But during server start up we are getting 
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax/persistence/spi/PersistenceUnitInfo.getSharedCacheMode()Ljavax/persistence/SharedCacheMode

This was fixed by adding the hibernate-entitymanager.jar file from 3.3.2 version. But this is not consistent with th 3.5.0 documentation.

Any pointers are highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

There's a `hibernate-entitymanager-3.5.0-Final.jar` (as well as some newer versions) in the [JBoss.org public repository](https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public/).

The easiest way to make sure you have the correct dependency JARs is to use a dependency management tool like Apache Maven.  In Maven you can reference Hibernate EntityManager like so:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
    <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

And that will pull in all the necessary JARs (for my project, using Hibernate EntityManager 3.5.4-Final), it wants to pull in hibernate-core, hibernate-jpa-2.0.-api, slf4j-api, hibernate-annotations, javassist, and cglib.  (See the attached image, snapshotted from NetBeans's dependency graph utility.)

[image: dependency diagram]